# Android: Broadcast receiver won't receive boot up message

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've a class `MyBroadcastReceiver` that is registered to start at boot up. The manifest is below. I am running this via eclipse on a Android Motorola Xoom wifi only tablet - which is Android 3.2, API level 13 (from the dev.android site).

I have googled for this and tried a few things:

- put `android:exported="true"`
- used `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` to make sure it doesn't install on the SD card
- after installing on the device, I ran the app a couple of times before testing the bootup (as some links said Android 3.x onwards won't immediately start sending boot events to the app unless user has manually initiated it at least once)

However even now the broadcast receiver doesn't seem to run when the device boots up (based on logcat).

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mypack"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".MainCamApp" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      </activity>

     <service android:name=".UploaderService" />

     <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Code for broadcast receiver -

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyBroadcastReceiverX extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG = "Broadcast Receiver:";
    AlarmManager alarm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered onReceive.");
        alarm = (AlarmManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentUploadService = new Intent (arg0, UploaderService.class);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(arg0, 0, intentUploadService , 0);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pi);
        Log.i(TAG, "Alarm set. Exiting onReceive.");

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg0, UploaderService.class);
        arg0.startService(myIntent);
    }

}
```

---

Seems to be working now.. final manifest below if it helps -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      android:installLocation="internalOnly"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".MainCamApp" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      </activity>

     <service android:name=".UploaderService" />

    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiverX"  android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
          </action>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiverX"  android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
      </action>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You also have incorrect class name specified in manifest - it should be `MyBroadcastReceiverX` rather then `MyBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: hi, thanks I tried this.. reinstalled, started it manually twice, rebooted, checked log. but the broadcast receiver does not fire. i'm editing my post to inculde the receiver class also.

Comment: you need to correct your receiver class name (add X in the end). I've edited my answer

Comment: hi, yes my bad.. i had put the X this morning when trying out things. will try now.

Comment: Hi @Hit, it seems to be working now. The broadcast receiver does fire up and start the service. I seem to have a problem with the alarm/scheduling of the service now, but that's another thread. Thanks. My final manifest is updated in the question for other's knowledge.

Comment: @HitOdessit  Hi, I have a similar use case.  Why do you use '<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>' in the <intent-filter> ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code after receiving the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.

try this.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TEST", intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Entered onReceive.");
    alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentUploadService = new Intent (context, UploaderService.class);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentUploadService , 0);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pi);
    Log.i(TAG, "Alarm set. Exiting onReceive.");

    //no need to initialize intent twice
    // Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, UploaderService.class);

 context.startService(intentUploadService );
    }

}
```

Comment: hi shihab, is this required? By not having an if{}, it will respond to any event (by definition, BOOT_COMPLETED), correct?

Comment: @user1714373 : dear, in onReceive method() is always ready to get a system message. But U must be ensure that u catch the right Intent. Above code is ok. u paste code inside if(....){...}

Comment: shihab, i take your point. its better programming to test for the intent name. thanks!